# Turn web app into iOS app with push notification

Tags: ios, web-applications, push-notification

I developed a web application for a customer.
Web users can login and have their private account.
The application manager want to send "push" notification to users connected on iOS mobile devices.

Since I cannot achieve this feature with a simple web applications but I don't have resources to develop a native iOs application, the question is:

Is there a simple way to create an iOS "wrapper" to my web application and enable push notification for that app?

It will just be a webView pointing to my web application?

I'll be grateful if somebody can point me to resources, skeleton apps, alternative solutions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of app you are talking about would be rejected from the app store due to the poor value aported in comparison to your website. This is part of the policy apple applies for a while now.